# Is it possible to display a read only field on a work time that references a field from a parent work item?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am using the TFS 2010 Scrum template and want to modify the Task work item template so that I can display the PBI's backlog priority (read only).

I am familiar with editing the process templates, but not sure I can setup a field to pull data from another work item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no rules available to get data from other work items. If you want to do this, you can either use the eventing service (which is a service that is invoked on work item save for example) or you can create a custom work item control.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it would be easier ;)